# Google Maps IOS Show Routes

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

With the Google Maps IOS SDK, is it possible to show the route from one location to another location. I've googled but didn't find any good results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did the tutorial I posted below work for you?

Comment: My answer could be helpful, located at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811965/how-to-draw-a-path-one-place-to-another-place-in-google-map-sdk-ios/20171859#20171859.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdV7bCWuDYg) is a tutorial that shows how to do this and is linked to a github that has source code.  You basically have to write wrappers to do server requests to get a polyline between two locations and then you add it to the map.

Also, [look here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) for the full documentation and basic code snippets.

Good luck!